# SQL Server to SQL Server CE table data copy using SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I'm working on a Windows CE application, and I need to copy server table data to SQL Server CE database (local) using C# programming. I'm using Visual Studio 2008, SQL Server 2008 for the development.

Below is the code I'm working with, but it seems in VS2008 `SqlBulkCopy` isn't supported. Do we have any alternatives to achieve this functionality?

```
SqlConnection source = new SqlConnection(Con_s);// server connection string SQL Server

SqlCeConnection destination = new SqlConnection(Con_l);// Local connection string SQL Server CE DB
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("DELETE FROM ProductList", destination);
source.Open();

destination.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Products", source);

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

SqlBulkCopy bulkData = new SqlBulkCopy(destination);
bulkData.DestinationTableName = "ProductList";

bulkData.WriteToServer(reader);

bulkData.Close();
destination.Close();
source.Close();
```

Add: I have included both `using System.Data.SqlClient;` & `using System.Data;` in the code

Comment: The local SQL Server CE connection must use `SqlCeConnection` and `SqlCeCommand` !!

Comment: This has nothing to do with VS2008 - the problem is: `SqlBulkCopy` is **only** for "real" SQL Server (Express and others) - but **NOT** for the Compact Edition (which is really a totally different, separate product). But maybe [this project on CodePlex](https://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com/) could be of help to you

Comment: @jobin Can we know what kind of exception you are getting while compiling/executing the above code?.

Comment: SqlBulkCopy missing reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I cannot paste image in the comments,I am including it as answer.
SqlBulkcopy is present under System.Data.SqlClient namespace.
Just navigate to SqlBulkcopy namespace,you must get navigated to the below [image]

If not I think your dll is corrupted may be you need to reload new one.